# ASP.Net MVC 3 Unity IoC Disposal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC 3 Web application which uses Unity 2.0 as it's IoC container.

Below shows an example of my **Application_Start()** method in my **Global.asax** file

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

    container.RegisterType<IControllerActivator, CustomControllerActivator>(
        new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IControllerActivator>());

    //container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(
    //  new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(
        new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IUnitOfWork>());

    container.RegisterType<IListService, ListService>(
        new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IListService>());
    container.RegisterType<IShiftService, ShiftService>(
        new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IShiftService>());

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

My **HttpContextLifetimeManager** looks like this

```
public class HttpContextLifetimeManager<T> : LifetimeManager, IDisposable
{
    public override object GetValue()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Items[typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName];
    }

    public override void RemoveValue()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items.Remove(typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName);
    }

    public override void SetValue(object newValue)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items[typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName] =
            newValue;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        RemoveValue();
    }
}
```

My issue is that, the method **Dispose()** in the above class is never called when I put a breakpoint on it. I am worried that my IoC container instance is never being disposed of. Could this lead to problems?

I found this snippet of code which I placed in my **Global.asax** file, but still the **Dispose()** method never gets called

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (DependencyResolver.Current as IDisposable);
}
```

Can anyone help me with how to dispose of each instance of my Unity container?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity does not track the instances it creates nor does it dispose of them. Rory Primrose has an [extension that does the tracking](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2010/06/18/Unity-Extension-For-Disposing-Build-Trees-On-TearDown.aspx) and allows for the disposal of objects by calling `container.TearDown()`.

`LifetimeManagers` that clean up after themselves are on the [wishlist for Unity vNext](http://entlib.uservoice.com/forums/89245-general/suggestions/1672391-unity-lifetimes-teardown-should-dispose-objects-c).

Bootstrapping a new container instance is expensive if you do it on every request. So I would consider caching the container instance after you are done with all the registrations.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Unity.MVC3 nuget package. Then when initializing specify the HierarchicalLifetimeManager and your objects will be disposed of after each request.

```
container.RegisterType(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

It's as simple as that : )

Comment: The `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` disposes the objects created with that lifetime when the container it is registered with is disposed. If you do that on every request you will loose a lot of performance.

Comment: And yet I use it just fine : )   A child container is disposed of. See the unity.mvc3 package details: A library that allows simple Integration of Microsoft's Unity IoC container with ASP.NET MVC 3. This project includes a bespoke DependencyResolver that creates a child container per HTTP request and disposes of all registered IDisposable instances at the end of the request.

Comment: I had a look at the project before. It is simple to use and does the job. But I don't like the concept of child containers in general (that's a personal opinion though).The performance degeneration of setting up Unity's build pipeline for every request depends on how many registrations you have in your child container and the load of your web app.

Comment: @SebastianWeber: You are not the only one. Even Krzysztof Koźmic, the developer behind Castle Windsor, thinks about [removing](http://kozmic.pl/2010/06/01/castle-windsor-and-child-containers/) the concept of child containers from Castle altogether.